# OpenVPN Fails to Connect to Server Running on Private Server

Tags: linux, centos, openvpn, vpn

I have not used OpenVPN AS on cloud services. What I want to do is connect to a OpenVPN Access Server setup on a VPS. The server is CentOS 7 and the client is commandline openvpn for Linux. The OpenVPN AS admin UI says that the server is up and running. I have gone through all the steps and the currency limited is two users. 
When trying to connect by issuing the command "openvpn --config client.ovpn", I encounter alot of errors like the following (assuming 10.10.10.10 to be my VPS's IP address):

```
Tue Aug 20 11:16:20 2019 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 20 11:16:20 2019 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 20 11:16:20 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]10.10.10.10:1194
Tue Aug 20 11:16:20 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Tue Aug 20 11:16:20 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Tue Aug 20 11:16:20 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]10.10.10.10:1194
Tue Aug 20 11:16:24 2019 Server poll timeout, restarting
Tue Aug 20 11:16:24 2019 SIGUSR1[soft,server_poll] received, process restarting
Tue Aug 20 11:16:24 2019 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
Tue Aug 20 11:16:24 2019 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 20 11:16:24 2019 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 20 11:16:24 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]10.10.10.10:1194
Tue Aug 20 11:16:24 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Tue Aug 20 11:16:24 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Tue Aug 20 11:16:24 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]10.10.10.10:1194
Tue Aug 20 11:16:28 2019 Server poll timeout, restarting
Tue Aug 20 11:16:28 2019 SIGUSR1[soft,server_poll] received, process restarting
Tue Aug 20 11:16:28 2019 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
Tue Aug 20 11:16:28 2019 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 20 11:16:28 2019 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 20 11:16:28 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]10.10.10.10:1194
Tue Aug 20 11:16:28 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Tue Aug 20 11:16:28 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Tue Aug 20 11:16:28 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]10.10.10.10:1194
^CTue Aug 20 11:16:29 2019 event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Tue Aug 20 11:16:29 2019 SIGINT[hard,] received, process exiting
```

These errors go on and on forever, unless I already establish a VPN connection via another mechanism like AnyConnect. I assume this means that my ISP does identify OpenVPN traffic and does not allow it.
Is there any solution to this? 
I used to have a similar issue with ProtonVPN's cli app which relied on OpenVPN a while ago, and it never got solved. Should I give up on this or there are workarounds for it?

Comment: We're going to need a lot of detail to track this. Client OpenVPN configuration. Server OpenVPN configuration. (Omit certificates and user authentication details.) IP addresses of Client and Server. Confirmation that each can ping the other. Confirmation that you're not blocking port 1194 (TCP/UDP). Confirmation that the server process is running and listening. If you want to obfuscate details that's fine, but _tell us you've done this_ and ensure that you are self-consistent (change each octet's value consistently).